# Why does the Orthodox Church have a larger canon than Catholics or Protestants?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, old-testament, canon, oriental-orthodox

There's obviously a despite between Roman Catholics and Protestantism on which constitutes the canon with Roman Catholics having the Deuterocanonical's as scripture (ie one and two Maccabees), but the Orthodox Church has a much larger canon, in which contains three Maccabees, why does the Orthodox Church have a much larger canon than the Roman Catholics?

Comment: The Orthodox consider the Septuagint (LXX) to be authoritative, and some of the earliest forms of it that were used in the early Church included these additional books. With that said, some of the manuscripts did not include them. Whereas some scholars like Jerome opted only to include books that were present in all manuscripts (and in some cases, that he felt were originally written in Hebrew), others were content to pass on what they received and recognized that early hand-copied codices (pre-printing-press) had some variability.

Comment: Also, the concept of “canon” is more a western idea. The books were more fluid in the Eastern churches (and arguably still are, as some groups within Orthodoxy have different lists of books). The Orthodox were more concerned about the lectionary: books to be read aloud in liturgical settings, which didn’t mean other books should be excluded, but wasn’t as much about “authority” as in the west.